# store woocommerce checkout form data to custom table using api

Tags: wordpress

I want to send the values of the checkout form to my API in woo commerce when customer clicks on the place order button, so that i can store this data using API. But i don't know how to use hooks to achieve this. Please can anybody suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below hook once?
that will work when you will click on proceed to checkout button from cart page. That will return all fields . And in this you can pass your API and pass your details ,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    print_r($fields);   
    $url= 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/United States'; //API URL
    $MSAPI_Call = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($MSAPI_Call, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($MSAPI_Call, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
    curl_setopt($MSAPI_Call, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($MSAPI_Call);
    print_r($response);      
    die();    
     return $response;
}
```

Comment: Works fine!! But some mistake from my side. I actually want all these fields on place order button so i can get details filled by customers and send to my api.

Comment: I am also using a plugin **WooCommerce Payment Gateway - Inspire** which provide following fields to me: 1)Credit Card number 2) Expiration date  3) Card security code . So i want to send these fields also

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_change_status_function' );
function my_change_status_function( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    //$order->update_status( 'completed' );
 print_r($order);
 die();
}
Try this one , that will call after payment that will work and also give you all order information.

Comment: **add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_change_status_function' ); function my_change_status_function( $order_id ) { $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); //$order->update_status( 'completed' ); print_r($order); die(); } ** works for me. Its Amazing!! Thanks for your help. Thanks a tonn.

Answer (score 0):

Put one of below hook in your function.php file and check proces after place and order or at the time of checkout process.Make you function  as per hook.

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'my_status_pending',  1, 1  );

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'my_status_pending',  1, 1  );

Or if you want to add after payment try below code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;
    $user_info = get_userdata($myuser_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['product_id']==24) {
          // Do something clever
        }
    }
    return $order_id;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!! I wants to call my api when clicks on place order button. Where should i have to give the link of my api??

Comment: Can you please give me any example or parameter of your API  OR you can explain me what exactly you want?
 
Because here as per my understanding i am thinking that in your site you have one order button and when button is click you can call above hooks and when you perform your action at that above hook will execute automatically and give you all your order details. 

and from that details in same hook function you can call you API and send data in that hook function.

In this let me clear if i am going any wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.My requirement is when i click on checkout button then i want to call one of my custom api to store data in my another table.

Comment: Like my api is (http://www.example.com/saveData) i want to call this api on my checkout button with all parameters that i need to send with this API , it would be 1)firstname 2)lastname 3)company that all contains in checkout form

Comment: i have added another code which will give you full order array. Please try that.